# Get only modified files using VSSGET ant task

Tags: file, ant, vssget

How can i get only modified files using VSSGET ant task? Something like update in SVN.
I try to find this option in the documentation, but i didn´t find.
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/vss.html

Comment: Info about vss: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/vssourcecontrol/thread/a8d5752d-0cf5-4034-81a5-4824e6e168e2

Answer (score 0):

Trying to achieve this stuff with simple Ant script probably isn't possible, however doing it with **inventive** Ant scripts should be.

There is no out of the box support for this. You will have to write a script which "remembers" the last build, save it to a file or something and then when you run the script another time you should check for differences. Vss history comes to mind. You have to combine all those together and then you could get your result.